# Bash completion for custom command to complete static directory tree

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion

I would like to add a custom completion spec for bash's Programmable Completion that does the following: whenever the command entered is `foo`, I would like to do filename/directory completion for the partial token after `foo`, but relative to a fixed directory (say `/a/b/c`) rather than the current working directory.

For example, suppose `/a/b/c` contains the files

```
hello goodbye cheers directory
```

and `/a/b/c/directory` contains the files

```
adieu ciao
```

Then, typing `foo go<TAB>` should complete `go` to `goodbye`, and typing `foo dir<TAB>ci<TAB>` should complete the argument first to `directory/` and then to `directory/ciao`, regardless of what my current working directory is.

I was hoping to be able to set this up with just a single call to `complete`, but after reading the manual, it doesn't appear that I can do this. Can it be done? And, if not, how could I add a compspec to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a custom completion function like the following:

```
_foo () { 
  local cur
  COMPREPLY=()
  cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  k=0
  i="/a/b/c" # the directory from where to start
  for j in $( compgen -f "$i/$cur" ); do # loop trough the possible completions
    [ -d "$j" ] && j="${j}/" || j="${j} " # if its a dir add a shlash, else a space
    COMPREPLY[k++]=${j#$i/} # remove the directory prefix from the array
  done
  return 0
}
```

And then register the function to be used with your command `foo`:

```
complete -o nospace -F _foo foo
```

Comment: Although I've already tested and accepted this answer (thanks, btw!), I'm still curious whether it can be confirmed that I _can't_ achieve the functionality I'm looking for using only the many and not completely documented command-line options to `complete`  (other than `-F`, that is).

Comment: @lambdacalculator You can work with `-P /a/b/c`, but that will always replace the completion pattern with the whole path. I don't think it's possible without a function.